# npm install error inside docker container

Tags: docker, npm

I am new to Docker. After logging into the container using docker run, and running the following command, I am getting error.

```
ubuntu@eef407281d9d:/usr/src/svx-frontend$ npm install


enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/svx-frontend/package.json'
npm WARN svx-frontend No description
npm WARN svx-frontend No repository field.
npm WARN svx-frontend No README data
npm WARN svx-frontend No license field.
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-42-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /usr/src/svx-frontend/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/svx-frontend/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/svx-frontend/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/src/svx-frontend/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-42-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.1447058929
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.1447058929'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.1447058929'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'npm-debug.log.1447058929' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/src/svx-frontend/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score -2):

To download and install node.js use commend:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

To download npm use commend:

```
curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

And run it.

I hope it's helpful

Comment: when i execute the above commands, it requires password for ubuntu like below.
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
After entering ubuntu password (even correct password), it says incorrect password like :
 sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts

Comment: Below the full command & response for reference: ubuntu@e4c4a6ae6c54:/usr/src/svx-frontend$ sudo curl -L npmjs.com/install.sh | sh [sudo] password for ubuntu: Sorry, try again. [sudo] password for ubuntu: Sorry, try again. [sudo] password for ubuntu: sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts ubuntu@e4c4a6ae6c54:/usr/src/svx-frontend$